# Does anyone know the translation of this character?

Tags: translation

[image]

What does this symbol mean? Does it even exist?

Comment: Translation questions are off-topic for this site unless prior research effort has been shown.

Answer (score 2):

It does exist. Mandarin pinyin pronunciation: kāng. It's a common surname, also means healthy.

Comment: Maybe it stands for “Connecticut” ;)